# ARM DCD working and Executing from RAM

Tags: linker, embedded, arm, greenhills

I am using MBD9F126(ARM Cortex R4) micro-controller. In that I am flashing code into ROM and then I am executing the code from RAM after RAM copy. I am using the Green hills compiler. Before the RAM copy I am executing basic board Initialization code.

```
    LDR r12, ADDRESS_START_PREINIT
    BLX r12
    ADDRESS_START_PREINIT:DCD Start_PreInit
```

Start_PreInit is board initialization function.  IF I am giving like this after BLX it'll branch to RAM location. As RAM copy is not done yet so it goes to unknown area.

Instead of this If I am writing

```
    bl Start_PreInit
```

Its working properly that is going to ROM location of code. I don't why compiler has such a behavior?
And also 
       ADDRESS_START_PREINIT:DCD Start_PreInit . Is it done during linking??

Comment: have you tried ldr r12,=Start_PreInit then blx r12?  in theory it does the same thing but you may find the difference between what you had and what you needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `bl Start_PreInit` instruction works because the branch target is encoded in the instruction opcode as an offset relative to the current `PC` (`r15`). Since `r15` is pointing to ROM, the target is another ROM address.

The `blx r12` instruction branches to the absolute address that was loaded into the `r12` register.

When you load the contents of `ADDRESS_START_PREINIT` into a register, what you're getting is the absolute address that the linker calculated for the `Start_PreInit` address.  Apparently the linker has fixed that to the RAM absolute address.

You might be able to fix the problem with a linker configuration or by performing some transformation on `r12` when it's loaded with the RAM address (something like `(r12 - RAM_START) + ROM_START`) before branching.  Or use the pc-relative encoding instead of the register-absolute encoding for the branch instruction if the target address is in range.